# How to show value calculated from input form to the screen

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I'm new to react, and am trying to get a form to accept input from 2 lists, and output a calculated value to the screen.  I used create-react-app to create the app and used the form sample from the react-bootstrap docs.  I now can get the user's input, and getting the correct value in my console log.  However, how do I output that randNum value to the screen?

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
import Fade from 'react-bootstrap/Fade'
import {CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group'
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [diceType, setDiceType] = useState('');
  const [diceNumber, setDiceNumber] = useState('');

  const rollResult = () => {
    const min = 1;
    const max = parseInt(diceType, 10);
    var randNum = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < parseInt(diceNumber, 10); x++){
      randNum += min + (Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)));
    }
    console.log(randNum);
  };

  const handleDiceTypeInput = e => {
    setDiceType(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleDiceNumberInput = e => {
    setDiceNumber(e.target.value);
  };

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="diceType">
            <Form.Label>Dice Type</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="select" onChange={handleDiceTypeInput}>
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="4">D4</option>
              <option value="6">D6</option>
              <option value="8">D8</option>
              <option value="10">D10</option>
              <option value="12">D12</option>
              <option value="20">D20</option>
              <option value="100">D100</option>
            </Form.Control>
            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
              Number of sides on dice.
            </Form.Text>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="diceNumber" onChange={handleDiceNumberInput}>
            <Form.Label>Dice Number</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="select">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
            </Form.Control>
            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
              Number of dice to roll.
            </Form.Text>
          </Form.Group>          

          <Button onClick={rollResult} aria-controls="diceRoll" aria-expanded={open}>
            Roll
          </Button>
        </Form>

        <div id="diceRoll">
          The result is: 
        </div>

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `use useState` for that as well.

Initialize randNum to `''` and then, the place where you are console logging, set the value there. Inside the return function you can access the value by curly braces as `{randNum}`

**Including only relevant part of your code:**

```
function App() {

  const [randNum, setRandNumber] = useState(''); // Initialization here

  const rollResult = () => {
    const min = 1;
    const max = parseInt(diceType, 10);
    var randNum = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < parseInt(diceNumber, 10); x++){
      randNum += min + (Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)));
    }
    setRandNumber(randNum) // Set Here
    console.log(randNum);
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        ...
        <div id="diceRoll">
          The result is: {randNum} // Show Here
        </div>
        ...
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any confusions.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `useState` variable and populate it within the button `onClick` handler:

```js
const{ useRef, useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [diceType, setDiceType] = useState('');
  const [diceNumber, setDiceNumber] = useState('');
  const [rollResult, setRollResult] = useState(0);

  const handleDiceTypeInput = e => {
    setDiceType(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleDiceNumberInput = e => {
    setDiceNumber(e.target.value);
  };
  
  const handleButton = () => {
    const min = 1;
    const max = parseInt(diceType, 10);
    var randNum = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < parseInt(diceNumber, 10); x++){
      randNum += min + (Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)));
    }
    console.log(randNum);
    setRollResult(randNum);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={handleDiceTypeInput}>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="4">D4</option>
        <option value="6">D6</option>
        <option value="8">D8</option>
        <option value="10">D10</option>
        <option value="12">D12</option>
        <option value="20">D20</option>
        <option value="100">D100</option>
      </select>
      <select as="select" onChange={handleDiceNumberInput}>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={handleButton}>
        Roll
      </button>
      <div id="diceRoll">
        The result is: {rollResult}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const app = React.createElement(App);
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```